# Not able to write a proper regular expression to remove multiple spaces

Tags: regex, sed, removing-whitespace

```
$ echo "Anirudh   Tomer" | sed 's/ +/ /g'
Anirudh   Tomer
```

I was expecting it to remove those 3 spaces between Anirudh and Tomer and give me result as `"Anirudh Tomer"`

I am a beginner. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable sed's extended regexp support with the `-r` flag.

```
echo "Anirudh   Tomer" | sed -r 's/ +/ /g'
```

In extended regular expressions, the `?`, `+` and `|` metacharacters must not be escaped (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions)). The `*` metacharacter works because it belongs to the [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

Comment: but why does `anirudh@anirudh-Aspire-5920:~/Desktop/testing/GET_REQ$ echo "Anirudh   Tomer" | sed 's/[ ]*/ /g'

 A n i r u d h T o m e r 
` works. I mean it should also not work unless I give the -r option

Comment: I expanded my answer in order to reflect your comment.

Comment: @Andrea: You need to say `@Anirudh Tomer` so the user is automatically notified of your comment.

Comment: @Den thanks for the reminder. Also, I've been reading on meta that the first three letters should also work, so I'm also testing it in this comment. :)

Comment: @Anirudh If it is the right answer for you, you should accept it. :) And if you really like it (and the other answers!), upvote it (them).

Comment: @And: sure sure!!! I always do that, if someone gives you a right answer you should do that. Thanks for the reminder. I don't even have an excuse for not accepting it. Frankly speaking I came back to see this post after 2 days, but I should have marked it that day itself.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to VIM regex, you need to escape the `+` quantifier with a backslash:

`sed 's/ \+/ /g'`

Comment: thanks dude!!! your answer solved my problem. However I will prefer to add the -r option to sed now in future to make `sed -r 's/ +/ /g'`  work

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Anirudh   Tomer" | tr -s ' '
```